# Deriving the expected value equation in chi-squared tests.

Tags: statistics, expected-value, education, chi-squared

I'm struggling to get my head around a statistics idea (I study medicine). In calculating chi squared, the expected value is first calculated by using the following equation: $\frac{\text{row total}\times \text{column total}}{\text{total}}$

This does not make logical sense to me, I will demonstrate with an example. [image]

This compares treatment with a drug (dexamethasone) vs placebo in a simple 2x2 table.

Ho = dexa has equal effect on death as placebo and H1 = dexa reduces death. We want to calculate no. people who died on dexa (482 cell).

Logically in my head, I would find the probability of death when on the placebo ($1110/4321$) and then multiply that probability by 2104 since its the total patients on dexa = 504. However this is not the case, the actual answer is $\frac{(2104*1592)}{6425}$.

Any help explaining the logic behind this equation would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the figure 504 come from? BTW remember that the values in your table are actual **observed** events, and the purpose of the row x column / total calculations are to find the **expected** numbers in each category under the hypothesis that mortality and treatment are independent

Comment: @DavidQuinn I suspect the thought is $\frac{1110}{4321}\times 2104 \approx 540.486$ and then a typo.  So treating the placebo proportion as a predictor of the treatment proportion

Comment: The idea is to get expected counts assuming $H_0$ (equal effect from Dexa and Placebo): Estimate $P(Yes)$ as $\hat P(Yes) = 1592/6425$ Then apply that to estimate number Dexa and Yes as $(1592/6425)2104 = 521.3335.$

Comment: In R: input the $2\times 2$ table as `TBL = rbind(c(482, 1622), c(1110, 3211))` Then do the test as `chisq.test(TBL)` you get significant P-value $0.01679$ and you can use `chisq.test(TBL)$exp` to get the table of expected counts; its upper-right count is  $521.3335.$ as shown in previous Comment.